# from Django forms to pandas DataFrame

Tags: django, pandas, input, formset

I am very new to Django, but facing quite a daunting task already.
I need to create multiple forms like this on the webpage where user would provide input (only floating numbers allowed) and then convert these inputs to pandas DataFrame to do data analysis. I would highly appreciate if you could advise how should I go about doing this?

Form needed:

[image: tabular form structure]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question and I am assuming you are familiar with pandas and python. There might be a more efficient way but this is how I would do it. It should not be that difficult have the user submit the form then import pandas in your view. Create an initial data frame Then you can get the form data using something like this

```
if form.is_valid():
    field1 = form.cleaned_data['field1']
    field2 = form.cleaned_data['field2']
    field3 = form.cleaned_data['field3']
    field4 = form.cleaned_data['field4']
```

you can then create a new data frame like so:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[field1, field2], [field3, field4]], columns=list('AB'))
```

then append the second data frame to the first like so:

```
df.append(df2)
```

Keep iterating over the data in this fashion until you have added all the data. After its all been appended you can do you analysis and whatever else you like. You note you can append more data the 2 by 2 thats just for example.

## Pandas append docs:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

## Django forms docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/

The docs are you friend